# Google Recaptcha - How do I change the default required validation message?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, recaptcha, grecaptcha

The default message if  I am not a robot is

> g-recaptcha-response is required

I want to change it to something else like

> Recaptcha is required

I tried the following but didn't work

```js
function onClickSearch(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();
  if (v.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').innerHTML = '<span class="k-icon k-iwarning">reCAPTCHA response is required.</span>';
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which validation library are you using?

Comment: I am currently not using any validation library.   I am doing this in  .NET CORE 2.2  Razor Page

Comment: What type of [reCAPTCHA integration](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro) are you using? (V3, V2, Invisible, Checkbox, etc.) Can you share your relevant markup?

Comment: I am using reCaPTCHA V2  

 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="@_config["GoogleReCaptcha:key"]"></div>

  window.onload = function () {
        var $recaptcha = document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response');
        if ($recaptcha) {
            $recaptcha.setAttribute("required", "required");
        };
    }


Tried the following but can get the right message to appear  on   check box not check